# Tkinter drop down menu not showing selection

Tags: python, tkinter, import, drop-down-menu, module

I have created a program that gets selection from the drop-down menu in Tkinter. When I run it from the same file the drop-down widget shows what I have selected.

[image]

But when I try running it from a different file by importing the function, the selection is not displayed.
I am able to select options from the drop-down but what i select is not showing up.

[image]

---

This is my code in the main file(test2.py) where the drop-down menu is created:

```py
import mysql.connector as sql
from tkinter import *
import re


def servicingwindow1():
    root2=Tk()
    root2.title("SERVICING")
    root2.geometry("320x300")
    root2.configure(bg='#ffa366')

    selcom=StringVar()
    selmod=StringVar()

    companies=["com1","com2"]

    cars=["car1","car2"]
    model_box=OptionMenu(root2,selmod,*cars)
    model_box.grid(row=3,column=1)

    name=Label(root2,text="Your Name")
    name.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=8,pady=(5,0))
    company=Label(root2,text="Car Company")
    company.grid(row=1,column=0)
    model=Label(root2,text="Car Model")
    model.grid(row=3,column=0)
    licenseno=Label(root2,text="Licenseno")
    licenseno.grid(row=4,column=0)    

    name_box=Entry(root2,width=35,borderwidth=2)
    name_box.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=(5,0))
    company_box=OptionMenu(root2,selcom,*companies)
    company_box.grid(row=1,column=1)
    licenseno_box=Entry(root2,width=35,borderwidth=2)
    licenseno_box.grid(row=4,column=1)

    submitbtn=Button(root2,text="SEND FOR SERVICE")
    submitbtn.grid(row=5,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=5,ipadx=50)
    root2.mainloop()
```

This is the code in my other file(test1.py) where I imported the function from the main file:

```py
from tkinter import *
from test2 import servicingwindow1

root=Tk()
root.title("LOGIN")
root.geometry("300x200")
root.configure(bg='#66d9ff')

password=Label(root,text="PASS")
password.grid(row=2,column=0)

pass_box=Entry(root,width=35,borderwidth=2)
pass_box.grid(row=2,column=1)

p="test"
def submitpass():
    if pass_box.get()==p:
        passshow=Label(root,text="CORRECT OTP")
        passshow.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=8,pady=(5,0))
        servicingwindow1()
    else:
        passshow=Label(root,text="INCORRECT OTP")
        passshow.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=8,pady=(5,0))

checkbtn=Button(root,text="CHECK OTP",command=submitpass)
checkbtn.grid(row=3,column=0,columnspan=2,padx=10,pady=5,ipadx=50)

root.mainloop()
```

How do I display the selection when running from the other file?

Comment: Better provide a [mre].

Comment: @acw1668 I'm sorry but i thought i did. can you tell me what is missing so that I can edit my question?

Comment: It means that you need to post minimal code that we can execute to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @acw1668 is it correct now ? but idk how others will execute the file because they don't have the database in SQL. for that should I create a new code similar to my original code for my question ?

Comment: You can use dummy data instead of getting them from database.

Comment: thnk you , now ill edit the question

Comment: Your issue is that you have used two instances of `Tk()`.  Use `Toplevel()` for child window, i.e. `root2`.

Comment: @acw1668 i edited the question and used dummy data so that it can be executable.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you, ill try using `TopLevel()` for child window .